# Map containing functions not returning the correct results to stdout

Tags: bash, go, integration-testing

I'm trying to a simulate a *test integration framework*. The idea is to run all my test functions from one main function. It executes the tests but the output does not replicate the same result as the older function which delivers the correct results.

The tests are calling a Swagger API in a complete isolation inside a docker, where the Swagger API application and its database are up and running.

When `TestInfrastructure()` finishes it returns to a bash function, which prints out to the console the results.

I don't understand the mismatch between these two methods.

Old function that delivers the correct result:

```
func TestInfrastructure() error {
    cvn := cvn.New("x-corr-man")

    if err := TestCreateServiceSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestCreateServiceSwitch failed - %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestCreateServiceSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestCreateBorderSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestCreateBorderSwitch failed - %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost\n\t\t %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost\n")
    }
    if err := TestCreateBorderSwitchPair(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPair\n\t\t %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPair\n")
    }
    if err := TestCreateLag(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestCreateLag: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestCreateLag\n")
    }
    if err := TestListServiceSwitches(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestListServiceSwitches: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestListServiceSwitches\n")
    }
    if err := TestListBorderSwitches(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestListBorderSwitches: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestListBorderSwitches\n")
    }
    if err := TestListLags(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestListLags: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestListLags\n")
    }
    if err := TestDescribeServiceSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestDescribeServiceSwitch: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestDescribeServiceSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestDescribeLag(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestDescribeLag: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestDescribeLag\n")
    }
    if err := TestUpdateServiceSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestUpdateServiceSwitch: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestUpdateServiceSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestUpdateBorderSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestUpdateBorderSwitch: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestUpdateBorderSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestPatchLag(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestPatchLag: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestPatchLag\n")
    }
    if err := TestDeleteServiceSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestDeleteServiceSwitch: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestDeleteServiceSwitch\n")
    }
    if err := TestDeleteLag(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestDeleteLag: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestDeleteLag\n")
    }
    if err := TestDeleteBorderSwitch(cvn); err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - TestDeleteBorderSwitch: %s\n", err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - TestDeleteBorderSwitch\n")
    }

    return nil
}
```

old function test results to the console

```
=======================| Running integration tests |=======================
TestListNetworks tests...
    PASSED - TestNoFilter
    PASSED - TestAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestRemoteAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestRemoteAccountAndAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestNetworkUUIDNotFound
    PASSED - TestNetworkUUIDSFound
No regressions discovered
TestInfrastructure tests...
    PASSED - TestCreateServiceSwitch
    PASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitch
    PASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost
    PASSED - TestCreateBorderSwitchPair
    PASSED - TestCreateLag
    PASSED - TestListServiceSwitches
    PASSED - TestListBorderSwitches
    PASSED - TestListLags
    PASSED - TestDescribeServiceSwitch
    PASSED - TestDescribeLag
    PASSED - TestUpdateServiceSwitch
    PASSED - TestUpdateBorderSwitch
    PASSED - TestPatchLag
    PASSED - TestDeleteServiceSwitch
    PASSED - TestDeleteLag
    PASSED - TestDeleteBorderSwitch
No regressions discovered
Integration tests successful
```

New func. that I want to use instead of old function

```
func TestInfrastructure() error {
    cvnNew := cvn.New("x-corr-man")
    testFunctions := map[string]func(cvn.CVN) error {
        "TestCreateServiceSwitch": TestCreateServiceSwitch,
        "TestCreateBorderSwitch": TestCreateBorderSwitch,
        "TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost": TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost,
        "TestCreateBorderSwitchPair": TestCreateBorderSwitchPair,
        "TestCreateLag": TestCreateLag,
        "TestListServiceSwitches": TestListServiceSwitches,
        "TestListBorderSwitches": TestListBorderSwitches,
        "TestListLags": TestListLags,
        "TestDescribeServiceSwitch": TestDescribeServiceSwitch,
        "TestDescribeLag": TestDescribeLag,
        "TestUpdateServiceSwitch": TestUpdateServiceSwitch,
        "TestUpdateBorderSwitch": TestUpdateBorderSwitch,
        "TestPatchLag": TestPatchLag,
        "TestDeleteServiceSwitch": TestDeleteServiceSwitch,
        "TestDeleteLag": TestDeleteLag,
        "TestDeleteBorderSwitch": TestDeleteBorderSwitch,
    }

    for functionName, executeTestFunction := range testFunctions {
        if err := executeTestFunction(cvnNew); err != nil {
            return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - %s: %s\n", functionName, err.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - %s\n", functionName)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

New function test results to the console

```
=======================| Running integration tests |=======================
TestListNetworks tests...
    PASSED - TestNoFilter
    PASSED - TestAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestRemoteAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestRemoteAccountAndAccountFilter
    PASSED - TestNetworkUUIDNotFound
    PASSED - TestNetworkUUIDSFound
No regressions discovered
TestInfrastructure tests...
    FAILED - TestDeleteLag: method DELETE is not allowed, but [GET,OPTIONS,POST] are

Integration tests failed
make: *** [Makefile:222: integration-tests] Error 1
```

Comment: Do your tests rely on executing in the defined order? i.e. the Create tests must run before the Delete tests?

Comment: Yes they should be run in the order they arranged in the map. Could that be the issue the order gets dangled up when running from the map?

Comment: Maps have no order. If order matters use a slice.

Comment: That'd be your problem. Maps are unordered: https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range

Comment: @JimB how would I go about using a slice instead of the map? As the map takes in a function as the value parameter?

Comment: I can add the tests to `testSlice := []func(cvn.CVN)error{}` but the reason for the map, was to use the keys as then test function name, can I extracted the name when using a slice instead of maps?

Comment: @JonB: use a struct to pair the name with the function, and any other data you may need. Look at pretty much any example of table driven tests in Go.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up with, using slice to hold the test cases, now the order is secured, and to extract the name for console output I use a reflect. I'm pleased with the solution, clean, minimal no code repetition.

```
func TestInfrastructure() error {
    cvnNew := cvn.New("x-corr-man")
    testFunctions := []func(cvn cvn.CVN) error {
        TestCreateServiceSwitch,
        TestCreateBorderSwitch,
        TestCreateBorderSwitchPairSameHost,
        TestCreateBorderSwitchPair,
        TestCreateLag,
        TestListServiceSwitches,
        TestListBorderSwitches,
        TestListLags,
        TestDescribeServiceSwitch,
        TestDescribeLag,
        TestUpdateServiceSwitch,
        TestUpdateBorderSwitch,
        TestPatchLag,
        TestDeleteServiceSwitch,
        TestDeleteLag,
        TestDeleteBorderSwitch,
    }

    for _, executeTestFunction := range testFunctions {
        if err := executeTestFunction(cvnNew); err != nil {
            return errors.Errorf("\tFAILED - %s: %s\n", fmt.Sprintf("%s", extractFunctionName(executeTestFunction)), err.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - %s\n", fmt.Sprintf("%s", extractFunctionName(executeTestFunction)))
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func extractFunctionName(i interface{}) string {
    return runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(i).Pointer()).Name()[5:]
}
```